# Cannot login to ssh - stdin: is not a tty

Tags: ssh, connection, tty, stdin

*FIXED*

If you have seen this in the login screen of your server...

```
stdin: is not a tty
```

...you know the trouble. Well. I've had the exact same problem on my root server. I tried several things to remount `/dev/pts` or `/dev/tty` but nothing worked and I wasn't able to open a second connection.

Then a friend of mine had the most basic idea to just restart the service "screen", which allows to create multiple virtual console sessions.

Guess what. The command...

```
service screen restart
```

...fixed the console sessions to work again. At the time the error occured, we had appox. 20 screens running.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
service screen restart
```

I believe our server just had too many tty sessions running (which screen sessions actually are) and couln't create a new one. We've had this problem only once before and we had about the same size of screens running.

After finding the bug, we also reinstalled "screen" by typing:

```
apt-get purge screen
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install screen
```

just to make sure it's a setup error. We haven't had any problems since then.

**EDIT:** I contacted the server hoster to *increase the maximum allowed tty sessions* (which you should do too). The admin then set the maximum allowed tty sessions from 16 to 2048 (almost unlimited).